# awk blues.. What's wrong?

Tags: bash, awk, solaris

I have to read from a file 'main.csv' and print the output as below:

```
Set 4,1095,Set 1 or 4
Set 2,18277,Set 2 or 3
Set 1 or 4,Set 4,944
Set 2,1373,Set 2 or 3
Set 4,83,Set 1 or 4
Set 2,14356,Set 2 or 3
Set 2,14800,Set 2 or 3
```

I tried below with respective outputs:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}{OFS=","}{print $12,$15}' main.csv
Set 4,1095
Set 2,18277
Set 4,944
Set 2,1373
Set 4,83

awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}{OFS=","}{if($12 == "Set 1" || $12 == "Set 4"){print "Set 1 or 4",$12,$15}else{print "Set 2 or 3",$12,$15}}' main.csv
Set 1 or 4,Set 4,1095
Set 2 or 3,Set 2,18277
Set 1 or 4,Set 4,944
Set 2 or 3,Set 2,1373
Set 1 or 4,Set 4,83
Set 2 or 3,Set 2,14356
Set 2 or 3,Set 2,14800

awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}{OFS=","}{if($12 == "Set 1" || $12 == "Set 4"){print $12,$15,"Set 1 or 4"}else{print $12,$15,"Set 2 or 3"}}' main.csv
,Set 1 or 4
,Set 2 or 3
,Set 1 or 4
,Set 2 or 3
,Set 1 or 4
,Set 2 or 3
,Set 2 or 3
```

First 2 "awk"s run fine, then why not the 3rd one ?

main.csv has 15 comma separated values per line with 12th value as either of below:

```
Set 1
Set 2
Set 3
Set 4
```

PS: I'm using bash on Solaris 10

I'm still high on "awk" issues, below is what I noticed... not sure why it's happening (I'm getting this on both Solaris 10 and RHEL 5)

```
awk -F, '{print "Var13->"$13,"\t","Var12->"$12,"\t","Var15 ->"$15}' < main.csv
Var13->0         Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->1095
Var13->1631      Var12->Set 2    Var15 ->18277
Var13->0         Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->944
Var13->2832      Var12->Set 2    Var15 ->1373
Var13->0         Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->83

awk -F, '{print "Var13 & Var15->"$13,"\t","Var12->"$12,"\t","Var15 ->"$15}' < main.csv
Var13 & Var15->0         Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->1095
Var13 & Var15->1631      Var12->Set 2    Var15 ->18277
Var13 & Var15->0         Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->944
Var13 & Var15->2832      Var12->Set 2    Var15 ->1373
Var13 & Var15->0         Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->83


awk -F, '{print "Var13 & Var15->"$13,$15"\t","Var12->"$12,"\t","Var15 ->"$15}' < main.csv
or
awk -F, '{print "Var13 & Var15->"$13,$15,"\t","Var12->"$12,"\t","Var15 ->"$15}' < main.csv
or
awk -F, '{print "Var13 & Var15->"$13,"\t",$15,"\t","Var12->"$12,"\t","Var15 ->"$15}' < main.csv

ar13 &  Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->1095
ar13 &  Var12->Set 2 27 Var15 ->18277
ar13 &  Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->944
ar13 &  Var12->Set 2 73 Var15 ->1373
ar13 &  Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->83
ar13 &  Var12->Set 2 56 Var15 ->14356
```

As you can see last 3 runs had eaten up the letter from "Var13" output and added some junk info.

Comment: You input file shows 3 fields you code refers to `$12` and `$15`?

Comment: Can you show us your input file?

Comment: Your code is fine and should have resulted in the obviously intended output reformat. I can only surmise that you ran your third version under different conditions. Run the test again, carefully.

Comment: As a stylistic choice, it's probably alot cleaner than `awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}{OFS=","}{print $12,$15}' main.csv` to write `awk '{print $12,$15}' FS=, OFS=, main.csv`.  Also, your version assigns OFS on every input record, which is probably not what you intend.

Comment: Personally I'd write `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print $12,$15}' main.csv` so it's clear that you want the FS and OFS to have the same value and only use that explicit value in one place but nbd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My money's on you having control-Ms at the end of your ".csv" file lines causing the first part of the displayed lines to get hidden.

This corruption is brought to you at no extra cost by the people who brought you Windows Vista, etc.

Run "dos2unix" on your ".csv" file and then try again.

If that doesn't work, run "where awk" and "awk --version" and tell us the result. On Solaris you must use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk, do not use /bin/awk or /usr/bin/awk as those are both old, broken awk.

Comment: I tried using both nawk and xpg4/bin/awk, I see that it doesn't add any junk info to the output, but it doesn't show the first column of results. I'm running this:

/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F, '{print "Var13 & Var15->",$13,"\t",$15,"Var12->"$12,"\t","Var15 ->"$15}' < main.csv

and getting this:

 Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->1095
 Var12->Set 2    Var15 ->18277
 Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->944
 Var12->Set 2    Var15 ->1373
 Var12->Set 4    Var15 ->83
 Var12->Set 2    Var15 ->14356

Comment: Did you run `dos2unix` on your ".csv" input file as I suggested? Also run `cat -v` on your input file so any control characters show up.

Comment: the file is created in Solaris... I just named it .csv to mean 'comma separated values'... I'll try the cat -v and update you the output !

Comment: cat -v reveals that at the end of line there is something like (^M) , not sure what this means though

Comment: It means exactly what I said - that your input file has control characters at the end of the lines and the awk script is printing the lines correctly but those control characters are causing the terminal to effectively backspace over the leading output characters so they disappear when vieweing the output. If those control characters are control-Ms (^M) then dos2unix will remove them.

Answer (score 3):

No need to vote for this, I just wanted to paste in some formatted code.

Your program is getting big enough to deserve its own code file where it can be formatted in a civilized fashion and compared to other versions. When we do this we can easily see that you are assigning OFS in an action on every input line. No harm done, but it's obviously unintended so you lose **[1337 points.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)** With that fixed we move on.

You can't diff a one-liner and learn anything. **[Running diff(1)](http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=1&page=diff&manpath=NetBSD-2.0)** on the nicely formatted code shows that only the output lines have changed, and so both programs are equally valid. You must have made the third run under different conditions. Perhaps a different input file?

```
BEGIN  {
  FS  = ","
  OFS = ","
}
{ if($12 == "Set 1" || $12 == "Set 4") {
    print "Set 1 or 4",$12,$15
  } else {
    print "Set 2 or 3",$12,$15
  }
}
```

---

```
BEGIN {
  FS  = ","
  OFS = ","
}
{ if($12 == "Set 1" || $12 == "Set 4") {
    print $12,$15,"Set 1 or 4"
  } else {
    print $12,$15,"Set 2 or 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Adversely `awk '{print $12,$15,($12~/Set [14]/)?"Set 1 or 4":"Set 2 or 3"}' FS=, OFS=, file`

Comment: @DigitalRoss, I lost 1337 points (fainting!!) :} !
What is diff(1) ?
Last two "awk"s have same codes to start with, just the print statements are different and that's what making me go bonkers !

Comment: I've updated the answer to hyperlink diff(1) and also 1337. Note that I may lose *1337* points *myself* for actually explaining it.

Comment: @DigitalRoss, Oh ! I feel like such a n00b :{!.. I'm still sturggling with the "awk" stuff.. is it because I'm using a Solaris machine.. I'll check the results on a RHEL as well...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Solaris. Be sure to read `man awk` to see how to run your awk program from a file and read `man diff` for more fun. I will suggest `diff -u oldprog.awk newprog.awk`

Comment: @DigitalRoss There definitely IS something wrong with Solaris! the default awk on Solaris (/bin/awk and /usr/bin/awk) is old, broken which which must never be used. On Solaris you need to use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk. Why they still keep shipping old, broken awk with Solaris is beyond me.